# Android: ClassCastException when adding a header view to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview, classcastexception

I'm trying to add a header to an ExpandableListView like so:

```
headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, null);
expandableListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
expandableListView.setAdapter(new SectionedAdapter(this));
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
 12-08 16:23:42.354:
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421): Caused by:java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
 12-08 16:23:42.354:   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421): at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:504)
 12-08 16:23:42.354: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421): at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:490)
 12-08 16:23:42.354:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:422)
 12-08 16:23:42.354:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421): at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:475)
```

This is happening at the call to `expandableListView.setAdapter(new SectionedAdapter(this))`, but I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out. I got rid of the runtime error by programatically setting the View's LayoutParams to ListView LayoutParams, like so:

```
headerView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

before adding the view. The reason being is found in the Android docs:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

which states that:

> These supply parameters to the
>   *parent* of this view specifying how it should be arranged. There are many
>   subclasses of ViewGroup.LayoutParams,
>   and these correspond to the different
>   subclasses of ViewGroup that are
>   responsible for arranging their
>   children.

So basically, if you are adding a view to another, you MUST set the LayoutParams of the view to the LayoutParams type that the parent uses, or you will get a runtime error.

Comment: I spent the last two hours trying to figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain this.. no one else has a very good answer anywhwere

Comment: gracias, 
Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 5):

Even though the above answer might work for many, there is still a better explanation. 
`ClassCastException` is the normal behaviour after calling `listview.addHeaderView` or `listview.addFooterView`.

The reason is that the initial adapter is wrapped in the `HeaderViewListAdapter`. 
To get your adapter use this code.

```
YourAdapter ya = (YourAdapter) ((HeaderViewListAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter();
```

[Code taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819996/3977935)

Comment: Your solution worked over Christopher solution. So if Christopher's solution doesn't work, try this guys!

Answer (score 1):

In my case this didn't work. I had to set a footerView to my listView before setting it's adapter. First I initialized my loadingView from a layout file in OnCreate method:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
loadingView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_view, null);
```

Then I used this workaround in the same method:

```
this.setIsLoading(true);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
this.setIsLoading(false);
```

Where

```
private void setIsLoading(boolean isLoading)
{
    this.isLoading = isLoading;

    if (isLoading) {
        listView.addFooterView(loadingView);
    }
    else {
        listView.removeFooterView(loadingView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put parent view to your inflated view.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, listview, false); // set listview as parent view
listview.addHeaderView(headerview);
```