# android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams class error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-linearlayout

I am having this error android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.

When using this code.

```
public void modifyingTextViews(){//This sets up a margin for the textviews.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llp.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 30);
        textview1.setLayoutParams(llp);
        textview2.setLayoutParams(llp);
    }
```

It conflicts with my touch methods or my load methods which consists of view flipper with 2 textview and a loader.

From what I understand from a guy with a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393775/android-classcastexception-when-adding-a-header-view-to-expandablelistview) is that it is because I am getting this error probably because of the arrangement of the view.

Now My question is how would I be able to tell which is my main view on a view flipper if I have different xmls. Also if there would be a quick fix to the problem that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: in the future, it'd be a good idea to display your stack trace and/or logcat output so we can know exactly what the problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what the issue is without knowing more (your xml code would be a start). Since you asked for an easy fix... I would just define everything in XML. That way everything is organized and you don't have to worry about setting `LayoutParams` at runtime.

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- layout #1 -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- layout #2 -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- fill in the rest here -->

</ViewFlipper>
```

Of course, this is a hypothetical example and you'll have to write the XML code to get the layout you want, but hopefully this gives you a good idea of where to start. Once you get it all set up, initializing the layout is simply a matter of calling `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: in my experience it's a lot harder to make mistakes when you code your layout in XML, rather than creating them dynamically at runtime :). glad it worked for you!