# ClassCastException when adding TextView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I would like to add programmatically to `LinearLayout` some `TextViews`. And I want to use `LayoutInflater`. I have in my activity layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     />
```

I have written in activity code like this below.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scale, linearLayout, true);
textView.setText("Some text");
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

My `scale.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="50dp"  
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/unit"
     />
```

At the line `TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scale, linearLayout, true);` I have fatal exception like this below.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.MyActivity}: 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

When I replace in problematic line `linearLayout` with null I don't have any exception, but the `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight` from my `scale.xml` are ignored and I can't see any margins around added TextView.

I have found question [Android: ClassCastException when adding a header view to ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393775/android-classcastexception-when-adding-a-header-view-to-expandablelistview) but in my case I have exception in first line in which I use the inflater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify the root view (`linearLayout`) in the call to `inflater.inflate()`, the inflated view is automatically added to the view hierarchy. Consequently, you don't need to call `addView`. Also, as you noticed, the returned view is the root view of the hierarchy (a `LinearLayout`). To get a reference to the `TextView` itself, you can then retrieve it with:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.scale, linearLayout, true);
TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(
    linearLayout.getChildCount()-1);
textView.setText("Some text");
```

If you were to give the view an `android:id` attribute in scale.xml, you could retrieve it with

```
TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. My `LinearLayout` don't have any child views in layout file. How can I use `getChildAt` method in this case? And I have exception when I try to use `inflater.inflate()` with `LinearLayout` as my `ViewGroup`. My applications works when I use `null` as `ViewGroup` but in this case I again can't use `getChildAt` method.

Comment: @woyaru - After `inflater.inflate` returns, the inflated `TextView` will have been added to `linearLayout`. The exception is coming because you are trying to cast the return value to a `TextView` when it is actually returning `linearLayout` itself. (`inflater.inflate` returns the inflated view only if the root view is `null`. If it is not `null`, then it returns the root view, not the view that was inflated.)