# ClassCastException for android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have designed the layout for one of my activities but i am getting strange error . This is simple activity actually it is main menu activity which contains imagebuttons in it.

```
"07-12 16:40:22.599: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
"
```

Here is my layout xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rpg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                            " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                             " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/profile_btn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/a1" />

                <TextView android:text=" " />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/share_btn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/a2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                              " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/a3" />

                <TextView android:text="  " />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/contacts_btn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/a4" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView android:text="                                 " />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/exit_btn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/a5" />

                <TextView android:text="  " />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/amazon_btn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/amazon" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ban2_mainmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ban_2" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ban1_mainmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ban2_mainmenu"
            android:background="@drawable/ban_1" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In java at first line of this code below i am getting error

```
 ImageButton amazon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.amazon_btn);
        amazon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0084FCDKS"));
                startActivity(browse);

            }
        });
```

Error is

```
07-12 16:40:22.599: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.colony.rpgbluetoothchatlite/com.colony.rpgbluetoothchatlite.Menu_Main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
07-12 16:40:22.599: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Comment: Once Just clean your project and run. And, restart your workspace and try it also

Comment: Change the relative layout to linear layout table layout will be applicable to this only as you also did not perfectly set property of xml file

Comment: @user1155908 no error in your xml code and just clean your project and run again.

Comment: Go to this link, It might be helps you

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393775/android-classcastexception-when-adding-a-header-view-to-expandablelistview>

Comment: @user1155908 your layout and xml are fine. try rebuild again

Comment: I had the same issue when moving a Spinner into a LinearLayout-- it kept crashing on me. Clean didn't fix it, but restarted Eclipse and deleting the app from my device did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `com.colony.rpgbluetoothchatlite.Menu_Main` class...

find out where you call something like this.. I made the variable button.. 
but yours should be something else...

What's happening is.. your `R.id.ban1_mainmenu` is a `RelativeLayout`... but you are trying to convert it to a different class... in this case I am converting to `Button` class.. which will throw the same exception you have...

```
Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.ban1_mainmenu);
Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.ban2_mainmenu);
```

to fix it..

```
LinearLayout btn1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ban1_mainmenu);
RelativeLayout btn2 = findViewById(R.id.ban2_mainmenu);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you paste your full logcat error? Coz I think you are trying to use one of the LinearLayouts defined in your xml file in your Java code (maybe one of the last two linearlayouts) and you have not declared them properly.

And try cleaning your project and run it once. Sometimes this happens in Android, I've noticed too.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears mostly due to wrong type casting. e.g. below code:
same error created trouble for me in `listView`
I'm pasting code:

```
List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // The below line of TextView will generate same problem..
                    TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
                    Toast.makeText(
                            ActivityName.this,
                            "Item with id [" + id + "] - Position ["
                                    + position + "] - Planet ["
                                    /*+ clickedView.getText()*/ + "]",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like all you need to do is a clean project. This sometimes happens when you first put a scrolView in place. A clean sweep should do the trick, however.